# Execute javascript function after php redirect

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, redirect

I have a page where a user creates an item to auction it. If he submits the item creation form, the browser automatically redirects him to the newly created page via the following line of php code:

```
header('Location: item.php?itemid='.$itemid);
```

I would like to display a notification right after the item creation (on the newly created page) saying that the item has been created. This is the (working) code I use to call the notifications:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $container = $("#container").notify();
            notifyItemCreation();
        });
    </script>
```

*EDIT:* I think people are misunderstanding the problem.
So my **sellitem.php** page contains a form to sell an item, if this is submitted it gets send to **createitem.php**, this is where I do the validation checks. 
If everything is okay this is where I redirect to the newly created **item.php?item='$itemid'** page. I want on this (**item.php?item='$itemid'**) page the notification to be displayed.

*EDIT2:* I do know how to create the item.php?itemid='$itemid' page, this gets done perfectly, it is the notification to appear that is the problem. I am using the notifications from http://www.erichynds.com/blog/a-jquery-ui-growl-ubuntu-notification-widget
Can the people who are downvoting also explain why they are.

Comment: I don't get what exactly your question and problem is. Please edit your question to make it clearer: Actually, right now you don't ask any question (which is quite obvious from the absence of any question mark).

Comment: the question is how to deal with a notification call in one page followed by a redirect statement and it has to pop up on the other page (only appear once, not every time the page is visited)

Comment: As I said, please edit it into your question (and this still **not a question**. A question always has a question mark at the end). Also, please do not simply append your edits and instead make it one clear question (as if written at the beginning with all required information)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use session variables. In the next request if a certain variable exists or indicates that the current item is new, you can echo the script tag and unset the variable.

Comment: This is what I was looking at, simple solution but did not think of it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could just wrap the JS in a condition

```
<?php if(is_numeric($itemid)){ ?>

  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $container = $("#container").notify();
            notifyItemCreation();
        });
    </script>

<?php } ?>
```

You could use ISSET() as well

Comment: I don't see how this solves my problem, I explained my problem a bit more in detail, could u explain the solution a bit more too? Thanks